# How do I forward a local port to a remote port through SSH?

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

For example, I want to bind localhost:2222 to remote:22

I want to be able to do this:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 2222
```

and end up on the remote server via SSH

Is this something that can be done using SSH?  All of the examples I've seen are around port forwarding from a remote machine elsewhere.  I just want to port forward LOCALLY to a remote server.

Edit: this is NOT a duplicate of the suggested duplicate.  I am not trying to access a port on a remote machine via a local port.

I just want to alias port X on my machine to 22 on a remote machine.  I'm not trying to tunnel here, which I thought was clear by my example.

Edit2: it it makes it more clear, I essentially want to proxy localhost 2222 to a remote server on port 22.

Comment: Your example is weird. To use local port forwarding, you need SSH access to the remote side in the first place, so this command `ssh user@localhost -p 222` would be just an unnecessarily complex alternative. Unless there are two remote computers: a "proxy" and a target. If you cannot reach the target but you can reach the "proxy" and it can reach the target, then it makes more sense. Or maybe you want to allow other computers to reach the remote via your local computer (make your local computer a "proxy" for others). What is your goal?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm sorry but your reply almost sounds like "why would you wanna do that?"

I have reasons for wanting to do this.  I'm just looking to see if it's possible.

Comment: I've seen users asking for unfortunate solutions, mainly because of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: You will get only generic answers because port forwarding by SSH involves four computers in general: (1) a client that starts `ssh`, (2) a server that listens with `sshd`, (3) a target to reach through the tunnel, (4) a computer that uses the tunnel to reach the target. In some circumstances some of them may be the same machine, so there may be three or two real computers involved, or even one if your goal is cumbersome enough. And there's local or remote forwarding. In your case there *might* be some confusion because you seem to want to use SSH to tunnel SSH.

Comment: Maybe by "I just want to port forward LOCALLY to a remote server" you mean (1) and (2) are your localhost, (3) is what you call "a remote server". If so, I expect (4) is yet another machine. Is this the case?

Comment: I agree it's an odd case.  Perhaps it would make more sense if I said I'm trying to proxy local port 2222 to a remote port 22.

Answer (score 0):

Local port forwarding, i.e. a tunnel local port to a remote host:

```
ssh <gateway> -L <local port to listen>:<remote hostname/IP>:<remote port>
```

Or tunnel a remote port to a local server:

```
ssh <gateway> -R <remote port to bind>:<local hostname/IP>:<local port>
```

Comment: What is gateway supposed to be in this case?

Comment: I slight misunderstood the question, that is another remote machine, being used to tunnel another remote machine via the gateway remote machine to the local machine. The principle still works with 2 machines. Localhost < remote host < another remote host.